# What happens if I kill Hakon, Gormaith Golden-Hilt and Felldir?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Hakon, Gormaith Golden-Hilt and Felldir are the 3 heroes that help you kill Alduin at the end of the main quest. All three of them are "un-killable" as they just fall down and then stand back up once all their health is drained. However, after a whole hour of determination I managed to get them all by the waterfall on the left of the map. I was then able to drain their health and use unrelenting force which caused them to fall down the waterfall; eventually they went down so far that they literally fell off the map and disappeared.

Now I'm wondering what will happen when I use any of the shouts that Tsun gives me:

- Word of Power – Hero, Call of Valor
- Word of Power – Champion, Call of Valor
- Word of Power – Legend, Call of Valor

I wonder if they will still appear?
Has anyone else tried this?

Comment: Question for this question I guess: If you have already set yourself up to be able to do this, why not use the shouts and see what happens?

Comment: I imagine nothing - as the spell probably loads different entities and not actually load up the area where the original NPCs were just to pull them to you and turn them into spirits.

Comment: -OP- turns out it just summons them as it normally would. :(
altho i am still rather excited to have killed npcs that were "un-killable" haha:)

Comment: Who says they are dead? You say they 'fell of the map and disappeared'. This does not automatically mean that you killed them.

Answer (score -1):

They appear as ghosts. Every word calls a different character, so it doesn't matter if you kill them.

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ They aren't ghosts maybe, but they are already dead.